# Powershell: bulk parametr set

Tags: powershell, bulkupdate

am trying to bulk edit "UsageLocation" for a list of users. Running against one UPN is working fine, but bulk not :-/

**CSV example**

```
UPN
user1@company.smt
user2@compamy.smt
user3@company.smt
```

**Import users from CSV**

```
$userlist = Import-Csv .\users.csv
```

**Set usagelocation before adding a license**

```
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "user@company.com" -UsageLocation "XY"
```

**Set UsageLocation for users from CSV**

```
$userlist.foreach(
    {
        Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.UPN -UsageLocation "XY"
    }
)
```

**Error returned**

```
Set-MsolUser : User Not Found.  User: .
At line:3 char:9
+         Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.UPN -UsageLocation "XY"
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Set-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.UserNotFoundException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetUser

Set-MsolUser : Invalid value for parameter.  Parameter Name: UsageLocation.
At line:3 char:9
+         Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.UPN -UsageLocation "XY"
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Set-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.PropertyValidationException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetUser
```

Any ideas, please? :-(
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please show the first 5 lines of your csv file

Comment: We can't see what your csv looks like.. Does it have headers and if so, does it have a column named `UPN`? What delimiter character is used?

Comment: Just edited/added. Thx guys

Comment: That csv file does not contain UserPrincipalNames. Looks more like sanitized SamAccountNames..

Comment: Perhaps you meant to do `-UserPrincipalName "$($_.UPN)@company.com"`?

Comment: Hi gents, in my CSV example I missed @company.smt.... In mine CSV there are regular UPNs gathered from DC in correct format "user@company.smt"

Comment: Any ideas, gents?